# How to redirect entire output of spark-submit to a file

Tags: linux, bash, apache-spark

So, I am trying to redirect the output of an apache spark-submit command to text file but some output fails to populate file.  Here is the command I am using:

```
spark-submit something.py > results.txt
```

I can see the output in the terminal but I do not see it in the file.  What am I forgetting or doing wrong here?

Edit:

If I use

```
spark-submit something.py | less
```

I can see all the output being piped into `less`

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`spark-submit` prints most of it's output to `STDERR`

To redirect the entire output to one file, you can use:

```
spark-submit something.py > results.txt 2>&1
```

Or

```
spark-submit something.py &> results.txt
```

Comment: Ah!!  Right, I forgot about the other stream!

Comment: How can I redirect to file as you said while still printing everything (output of print() + stderr) out to console ? If it's redirected I am not seeing anything on console.

Comment: @Kenny The output of `println` etc will be visible on console only if the spark jar is submitted in client or local mode.

Comment: @philantrovert it has always been submitted in client mode, and I do get both stdout (from print)+ stderr on console. I'd like to replicate everything normally on console (stdout+stderr) to a file. I notice that using your method, nothing is output into console anymore; all goes to the file. Keeping things visible on console gives me an idea where my program is, instead of having to open the file.

Comment: @Kenny You can redirect the stderr to stdout and then pipe it with `tee`. Something like this:
`2>&1 | tee -a results.txt`

Answer (score 5):

If you are running the spark-submit on a cluster the logs are stored with the application Id. You can see the logs once the application finishes.

```
yarn logs --applicationId <your applicationId> > myfile.txt
```

Should fetch you the log of your job

The applicationId of your job is given when you submit the spark job. You will be able to see that in the console where you are submitting or from the Hadoop UI.

Comment: I will have to check that out.  I am still confused though as to why I am getting a difference between `> results.txt` and `| less`