# How do I save outputs in AWS GLUE pyspark job

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, aws-glue

Hi I want to run some big sql query in AWS GLUE, too large to run on notebook so have to in glue job. how do I save the dozens sql output from glue job other than save them individually as csv? Is there a way to write to a file like running SAS batch job with outputting to .lst file?

THank you!!

Comment: What you mean by individually to CSV files? For all supported file formats https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-format.html

Comment: Hi thanks, which one can I use to output all my SQL query results as I run the glue JOB?

Comment: basically how do i do this on aws https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46429962/how-to-redirect-entire-output-of-spark-submit-to-a-file